# Merge multiple list into single dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to merge the following list to dictionary as follow:

```
resultant_dict = {}
key = [101, 102, 103]
values1 = [1,2,3]
values2 = [4,5,6]
values3 = [7,8,9]
```

the output should be:

```
output = {101: '147', 102: '258', 103: '369'}
```

Values being concatenate with each other. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The values should be `str`ings?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes, it should be string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather weird that the values in the resulting dictionary should be `str`ings, but if that is what you want, you can use `zip` and `join` in a single *dictionary comprehension*:

```
output = {k:''.join(str(x) for x in xs) for k,*xs in zip(key,values1,values2,values3)}
```

in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), or for [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7):

```
output = {k:''.join(str(x) for x in xs) for k,xs in zip(key,zip(values1,values2,values3))}
```

By using `zip(key,values1,values2,values3)` we create an iterable that will generate tuples of the form:

```
(101,1,4,7),(102,2,5,8),...
```

Now we use `for k,*xs` to unify `k` with the first element of every tuple, and the remaining elements are stored in `xs` (so `xs` is `(1,4,7)` for the first tuple).

Now we use `''.join(str(x) for x in xs)` to convert all the elements in `xs` to strings and we join these together.

Finally we have `k:''.join(str(x) for x in xs)` which is dictionary comprehension syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
resultant_dict = {}
key = [101, 102, 103]
values1 = [1,2,3]
values2 = [4,5,6]
values3 = [7,8,9]

for i in range(len(key)):
    resultant_dict[key[i]]=str(values1[i])+str(values2[i])+str(values3[i])

print resultant_dict
```